# Jasmine testing is not recognizing the function getCurrentNavigation(): this.router.getCurrentNavigation is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to testing a component that uses the feature `getCurrentNavigation()` to get data from navigation, my component is running normally without any error when i serve it with `ng serve`, but my testing is saying:

> Component2Component > should create TypeError:
>   this.router.getCurrentNavigation is not a function

This is what my component do to get the data:

```
constructor(public router: Router) {
  if (
    this.router.getCurrentNavigation() &&
    this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras
  ) {
    console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras);
  }
```

This is my test:

```
describe('Component2Component', () => {
  let component: Component2Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component2Component>;
  const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component2Component],
      imports: [CommonModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component2Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Why my testing is not recognizing this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `routerSpy` you provide when configuring your testing module has no function `getCurrentNavigation`. The only function it contains is `navigate` because that's what you defined when creating it through [`jasmine.createSpyObj`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/jasmine.html).

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
```

The problem could be solved by changing above line with the following one.

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['getCurrentNavigation', 'navigate']);
```

**Let `RouterTestingModule` do its job**

[`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) sets up the router to be used for testing and provides spy implementations out of the box. You're however overwriting this by providing your own `routerSpy`. Therefore you should get rid of your `routerSpy` and configure the testing module as follows.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [Component2Component],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterTestingModule]
}).compileComponents();
```

If you'll need access to the `Router` somewhere in a test function, simple retrieve it from `TestBed` as shown below.

```
it(test somethingcreate', () => {
  const router = TestBed.get(Router);
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching this error and you think you are doing things correctly (using the RouterTestingModule) but it is still not working,
double check that you imported RouterTestingModule in your imports array, not your declarations array, like I did!